# root interlacing condition?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, polynomials

Consider the two functions $P(x)=e^x$ and $Q(x)=e^{-x}$, for $x\in\mathbb{C}$. Clearly, $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ have no roots at all. Furthermore, it follows that
$P(x)Q'(x)-P'(x)Q(x)=-2<0$, for any $x\in\mathbb{C}$. The quantity $P(x)Q'(x)-P'(x)Q(x)$ is defined in the classical Hermite-Biehler theorem. I read somewhere that this would imply that the so-called "root interlacing condition" is satisfied. Well, I don't understand how interlacing follows in this case, where the functions don't even have roots.